# How can I add new mapper to the already Initialized Mapper?

Tags: automapper

I want to add new maps to the Mapper created. I studied this document

> http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances

but could not understand it. **The way I want is like this**

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<Contact, Person>();
                    cfg.CreateMap<Student, Class>();
                    etc..
                });
                //My other code
                //My other code

                cfg.CreateMap<X, Y>();
```

So I want to reach cfg again and use it to add new maps to existing mapper configuration. How can I add new mapper to the already Initialized Mapper?

Comment: Can show us your actual code, please?

Comment: Okey, I added @CodeNotFound

Comment: Why not using Profile. What do you not understand in Profile documentation?

Comment: I have already created a profile.                                                                        
public class OrganizationProfile : Profile
        {
            public OrganizationProfile()
            {
                CreateMap<A, B>();
                CreateMap<C, D>();
                CreateMap<E, F>();
            }
        }

Comment: So just call `cfg.AddProfiles(typeof(OrganizationProfile));`

Comment: I passed this part in some way, but I was hanging out somewhere else. Now I am getting the error "Parameter name: type" which is "object needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args." @CodeNotFound

Comment: So, add a constructor with 0 args or only optional args.

Comment: I still do not understand this place. Would you give a detailed example?